# Select image from the database and insert it in an update form

Tags: php, html

I got a column in my database with the filepath of an image: images/example.jpg.
What I want to achieve is that if they want to edit a product, the image is automatically selected by id so if they just want to change the name they dont have to upload the image again.
This works for every other field except the image...

This works for the value of the price in the form:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" value="<?php if(isset(Product::$price)) {print Product::$price;}?>">
```

How do I achieve this for the upload field? This is what I've got:

```
<input type="file" name="photo" class="form-control-file" id="photo" value="<?php if(isset(Product::$file)) {print Product::$file;}?>">
```

To test if the if part works I used code below to display the image and it works.

```
<?php if(isset(Product::$file)) {print "<img src='" . Product::$file . "'>";}?>
```

Comment: This `file` form field is for upload only, not editing. If you wish for them to change the 'name' of a file, provide a different field for just filename they wish (which can lead to security concerns allowing people to name files on the server).

Comment: @IncredibleHat Is there no way to fill in that field automatically so the user doesn't have to upload the file again?

Comment: You are confusing the meaning of the field. It is for uploading. Nothing more. If you do not want them to upload again, then provide a different field to do a different operation (like a input type=text, that is pre-populated with the filename text for them to edit).